# HTML <a> tag mailto generates wrong address

Tags: html, google-chrome, anchor, mailto, xdgutils

I am using ubuntu 15.04 and chrome. When i click on any html link with mailto protocol e.g.

```
<a href="mailto:myemail@example.com">Click to send me email!</a>
```

It opens my default email application (thunderbird) but populate address field with wrong address. It prepends /// to email address. So in above case, recipient will looks like this

```
///myemail@example.com
```

instead of

```
myemail@example.com
```

Same issue is with skype urls. i.e.

```
<a href="skype:myusername?chat">Click to chat with me!</a>
```

It will open skype window with wrong user by prepending slash (/) same happen as with email address.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: I already updated but it did't help

Comment: Not a great idea putting real-life email address in a public website, have updated it... hope you don't mind

Comment: Thanks, i did't noticed that....:)

Comment: What's your specific chrome version (`chrome://version`)? It works fine for me on `42.0.2311.153 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.

Comment: Side note that might not be related to your issue. You are not properly closing the anchor tag in the first code snippet.

Comment: @Huey Version 43.0.2357.81 (64-bit)

Comment: does opening mailto links in thunderbird work correctly on other sites?

Comment: @HalimQarroum <a> tag is properly closed and it works fine on firefox. Issue is only with chrome.

Comment: No, chrome open every mailto (mine and other sites on internet) with wrong email address.

Comment: Try in incognito / without extensions.

Comment: I'm using Windows and version "43.0.2357.81 m" of Chrome and it works with both Outlook (I don't have Thunderbird) and Skype. Can it have anything to do with chrome on ubuntu?

Comment: Yes i think it is something wrong with 15.04 and chrome. I have tested it on my colleague system with ubuntu 14.04 and windows and it works fine. Issue is only with ubuntu 15.04 with chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By purging gvfs, many programs starts to misbehave. It also made file explorer and desktop files inaccessible.

This is known issue in ubuntu 15.04 and hopefully solved in next stable release.

Answer (score 1):

There is issue of gvfs package on ubuntu `15.04` which is responsible for opening files or performing actions using default program.

`gvfs` package opens mailto with wrong address. Remove this package

```
sudo apt-get purge gvfs
```

And, It will work fine, for both mailto and skype.